# MySQL WKB geometry corrupted after QGIS manipulation - Unknown WKB type 535

Tags: qgis, shapely, geos

I have a quite complex issue.

I have been using MySQL (MariaDB to be specific) for storing shapely geometries. All went well until the customer wanted to slightly change the position of one point.

Since I am familiar with the capabilities of GIS software, I just logged into a database and opened layer via Layer - Add vector layer. I moved the point and thought everything was fine. However, SQLAlchemy did not return any object after this change. Record with my point deleted (this was SQLAlchemy doing).

I investigated a bit more and as for the database, produced wkb seems to be correct. I am able to translate it to the geometry_wkt column and back using ST_AsText/ST_GeomFromText in pure SQL. All in db.

So the issue comes probably from Python drivers, that cannot read point geometry generated with QGIS. I receive error

```
shapely.errors.GEOSException: ParseException: Unknown WKB type 535
```

I would normally skip this issue with running scripts with "to WKT" transformation, however, we have our system built on SQLAlchemy and I cannot easily change how it behaves.

Shapely 2.0.1
QGIS 3.32.3-Lima
GEOS in shapely seems to be newer version compare to one in QGIS.

It all seems like QGIS is adding some extra data that cannot be understood by Python libraries.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkb
from modules.db_config import *
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class DataBaseManager():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.conn = mariadb.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        except mariadb.Error as error:
            if error.errno == 2003:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Cannot connect to do DB, pls make sure you use VPN connection!")
            else:
                print(error)

        connection_string = f"mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
        self.engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
        self.data_table = ""
        self.database = database

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
        self.engine.dispose()

    def get_sql_to_df(self, sql, params):
        with self.engine.connect() as connection:
            df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection, params=params)
        return df

    def get_drone_calc_positions(self, race_unique_id):
        sql = "SELECT * FROM DroneCalcPosition WHERE race_unique_id=%s"
        df = self.get_sql_to_df(sql, params=(race_unique_id,))
        return df

    def get_drone_calc_positions_as_gpd(self, race_unique_id):
        df = self.get_drone_calc_positions(race_unique_id)
        df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(wkb.loads)
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
        gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"
        return gdf
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dbmngr = DataBaseManager()
    x = dbmngr.get_drone_calc_positions_as_gpd(91)
    print(x)
```

Comment: might be a version missmatch - https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsWkbTypes.html suggests there are new types/constants added in 3.30, so try updating shapely